# Logic- Prove ⊢¬p⇒(p⇒(p⇒q)) using Fitch System with no premise.

Tags: logic, computer-science

This question has been bugging me all day. I did it by assuming

(1): ¬(¬p⇒(p⇒(p⇒q))) and 
(2): using bunches of implication introduction

The first one didn't work out at all. I thought in order to create a contradiction, I will assume ¬(¬p⇒(p⇒(p⇒q))), but all the symbols were implications, thus I figured there's no way I could solve it this way.

As for the second method, by repeatedly using implication introduction, it ended up needing me to prove p⇒q, so I try to use the principle of explosion to create q, but I'm stuck on how to create p and not p solely by p. Plus how does ¬p⇒p work out anyway?

It would truly be lovely if anyone can help me out.

P.S. Sorry for grammatical errors, English is not my mother language.

Comment: Please post your work, until you get stuck.

Comment: @amWhy I'm sorry but I'm not able to post my work up because I'm short of reputation points. I'll edit my post and give a more thorough description.

Comment: @Ang.: There is no reputation point requirement for editing your own question.

Comment: Does your proof system have a "principle of explosion" rule (from $A$ and $\neg A$ conclude $B$)?

Comment: Assume $\lnot p$ and assume $p$.

Comment: This is a contradiction, and from a contradiction you can infer a formula whatever.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have already edited my post, but I was not able to upload photos of my work. I did try to use the principle of explosion to create q, but I'm stuck on how to create p and not p solely by p.

Comment: @Ang.: Why would you need to create your contradiction "solely by $p$"? In order to get to the point where you need $q$, you will have assumed $\neg p$ and then assumed $p$ and then assumed $p$ once more. Just two of those assumptions will constitue a contradiction. You even get a choice of whether to use the first assumption of $p$ or the second assumption of $p$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you so much for this. I completely understand it now!!

Comment: 1) assume $\lnot p$; 2) assume $p$; 3) derive $(p \to q)$ by [$(\lnot E)$](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) followed by [$(\bot E)$](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for your help, too!!

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Comment: @Ang. You do not need to create photos of your work.  Indeed, doing so is actually discouraged.  Type things out.  Here's a [tutorial for mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you for this information, I'll start using mathjax from now on :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem thanks to people making comments. If I'm not mistaken this is probably right.

```
1         ¬P         Assumption    ]
2          P         Assumption   ]| 
3          P         Assumption  ]||
4        P^¬P        ^-I(1,3)    |||
5          ⊥         ¬-E(4)      |||
6          Q         ⊥-E(5)      ]||
7        P⇒Q        ⇒-I(3-6)     ]|
8      P⇒(P⇒Q)     ⇒-I(2-7)      ]
9   ¬p⇒(p⇒(p⇒q))   ⇒-I(1-8)
```

Comment: But you can simplify it... Omit 3 and at 6 introduce directly $P \to Q$ by $\bot$-E.

Comment: Yes, I do know about that. But I feel like this is a newbie (like me) question, so I would like to keep it super clear :).

Comment: The fact that you can derive *any* statement --compound as well as atomic-- from a contradiction, is a *very important lesson*. Once a contradiction is derived in a subproof, *any further effort is redundant*; you can just immediately state whatever you want *that subproof* to conclude. $$\tiny\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{}{\fitch{\neg p}{\fitch p{\fitch p{\bot\\q}\\p\to q}\\p\to(p\to q)}\\\neg p\to(p\to(p\to q))}\quad\text{verus}\quad\fitch{}{\fitch{\neg p}{\fitch p{\bot\\p\to q}\\p\to(p\to q)}\\\neg p\to(p\to(p\to q))}$$